# saving route while still connected to wifi

Tags: wi-fi, internet, google-maps, cache, data-plan

In Google Maps is there a way to save a route while you're still connected to wifi so that it saves your data plan? Does scrolling through the map while still connected to wifi help because then the points get cached?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just cache the route portion of the map using the `Make available offline` feature. Then, all need afterwards is the GPS, which doesn't use your data plan.

Comment: How do I use `Make available offline` feature?

Comment: @Celeritas It's in Google Maps. Open the context menu (In my S2, it's the left softkey button). You should see `Clear Map`,  `Make Available offline`, `Settings`, `Help`. When you click that `Make Available offline`, it will ask you to select an area you want to cache.

Comment: @geff_change what difference does it make when you zoom in or out on a selected area? For example is it only stored on the exact zoom level so if you were zoomed in farther it would use your data plan?

Comment: @Celeritas The area inside the box will be cached. The more Zoomed Out you are, the more area is cached. So, that will take a bit longer to cache, as more data will be downloaded. There is a minimum Zoom Out level. If you're past that level, you can't cache the area. You need to Zoom In a bit.